# Insert two records at once into two tables where one table uses the other as foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have two tables:

- `Employee`: EmpId (PK), EmpName .
- `EmployeeDetails` : Id (auto increment), EmpId (FK to Employee table), Address, ZipCode .

I'm using Entity Framework 6.

When I want to insert a new `Employee`, I must do two transactions, meaning use `SaveChanges()` twice, in order to insert a new employee and only then use its `Id` as a foreign key in `EmployeeDetails` .

Is is possible to do that in one transaction ?

Thanks

Comment: Is "details" inside Employee? If so, you can do employee.EmployeeDetails  = empDetails. Then call SaveChanges. EntityFramework will take care of the rest. Show us your classes/mappings

Comment: @jpgrassi : No , they are two separated classes connected with a foreign key , the `Id` of `Employee` is a foreign key of `EmployeeDetails `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **easily** do this in a single step:

```
using (YourDbContext ctx = new YourDbContext())
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    // set the values for "emp"

    emp.EmployeeDetail = new EmployeeDetails();
    // set the employee details

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you create the `EmployeeDetails` as part of the `Employee`, you can just save the `Employee` alone - and EF will store **both** entities (as an "entity graph") and set up the FK constraints between them properly - all in a single step

Comment: What do you mean by "part of the Employee" ? They are two separated classes connected with a foreign key , the `Id` of `Employee` is a foreign key of `EmployeeDetails` .

Comment: Well, if the tables are connected on the database level, then your C# class for `Employee` *most likely* has a *navigation property* for the `EmployeeDetails` that belongs to that employee

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your model a bit. Details is "part" of Employee. If you create the entities in this way, when you insert an employee, entity framework will take care of the rest for you:

**Employee**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    public EmployeeDetails  EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**Details**

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Than you can do this:

```
using (dbContext context = new dbContext())
{
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    emp.EmpName = "John";
    emp.EmployeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails 
    {
        //details fields
    };

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```